# Warning when trying to run Anagram(John Bentley-Programming Pearls)-C

Tags: c, qsort

completely new to C. just trying to get the hang of linux and C programming by getting John Bentley's Anagram (column 2 I believe)program to run. Pretty sure ive copied this code verbatim(had to add headers, etc) but im receiving a warning, which when compiled and run with my squash.c program gives an undesired output. ill admit, i dont even know how this charcomp function behaves, or what it even does. (some enlightenment there would also be nice).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int charcomp(char *x, char *y) {return *x - *y;}

#define WORD_MAX 100
int main(void)
{
        char word[WORD_MAX], sig[WORD_MAX];
        while (scanf("%s", word) != EOF) {
                strcpy(sig, word);
                qsort(sig, strlen(sig), sizeof(char), charcomp);
                printf("%s %s\n", sig, word);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Here's the warning.

```
sign.c:13:41: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (char *, char *)'
      to parameter of type '__compar_fn_t' (aka 'int (*)(const void *, const
      void *)') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                qsort(sig, strlen(sig), sizeof(char), charcomp);
                                                      ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:766:20: note: passing argument to parameter '__compar'
      here
                   __compar_fn_t __compar) __nonnull ((1, 4));
                                 ^
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort

Comment: Programming Pearls as language introductory book? Weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function takes a comparison function as a fourth argument, with the following signature:

```
int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)
```

Therefore, to avoid compiler warnings, you have to modify you `charcomp()` function in the following way, to fit that signature:

```
int charcomp(const void *x, const void *y) { return *(char *)x - *(char *)y; }
```

Your `charcomp` function just takes two `char*` pointers to and compares first their first characters.